# What is wrong in my config.xml regarding orientation on android?

Tags: config, phonegap-build, screen-orientation

I have tried many and different things to do a simple thing, make my phonegap build app to lock the orientation to landscape.

The current and unwanted (not to mention ugly) behavior is that when i start my android app, for a few seconds, i see the screen (and it's content) in portrait mode and then it "locks" itself to landscape as it should.

What is wrong with my config.xml? what could be missing?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="myid"  version="0.8.7" >
    <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest/application" >
        <application android:debuggable="false" />
        <activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation" android:name=".Activity.SplashScreenActivity" />
    </gap:config-file>

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" overwrite="true">
        <false/>
    </gap:config-file>
    <preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
    <preference name="screen-orientation" value="landscape" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
    <name>myappname</name>

    <description>
       best app
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />

    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />

    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" />

    <platform name="android">
        <!-- icons for android -->
        <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
    </platform>

    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="fr-xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xxhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-xxhdpi" />

    <!-- -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />

    <!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

    <!-- iPhone 6 -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />

    <!-- iPad -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />

    <!-- Retina iPad -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />



    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
        <param name="APP_ID" value="1636377466592822" />
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="myfacebookapp" />
    </gap:plugin>

    <gap:plugin name="com.sharinglabs.cordova.plugin.cache" version="1.0.0" />

    <gap:plugin name="com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.lowlatencyaudio" version="1.1.3" />

    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.4.0" />

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" version="0.2.13" />

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.12" />

    <gap:plugin name="net.yoik.cordova.plugins.screenorientation" version="1.3.1" />

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.3.4" />

    <gap:plugin name="com.adobe.plugins.gaplugin" />

    <gap:plugin name="net.bgta.phonegap.plugin.appversion" version="1.1.1" />

    <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> too much test devices have this rotation stuff (in android), so is it
>   solvable?

My opinion is a widespread solution will take some time.

For instance, I own a [Sprout Channel Cubby](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Sprout-Channel-Cubby-7-Tablet-16GB/38573923) which I bought for development for a client project. It costs about $100. I also have a [Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab/GT-P3113TSYXAR-specs). There is a difference between the two.

I play *Words with Friends*, which always demands portrait mode. On the Cubby, I often see the program rotating, because the default mode of the Cubby is Landscape. On the Samsung, I also see it rotating (if I am in landscape mode), but instead the App changes to portrait mode before the screen flips. I believe this happens because the Samsung defaults to portrait mode.

In other words, if the end user has set the viewing mode to "auto-rotate", you can force the App to the correct mode, but there will always be some *residual effects*, and the amount of that *effect* depends highly on the OS implementation, the hardware, and programming.

Add to this there are thousands of Android models in existence (See the article from OpenSignals). At what point, will *residual effects* be minimal?!? This is a hard question to answer.

Answer (score 1):

@totothegreat,
you have several issues with your `config.xml`

1. Use the [Phonegap Build Docs](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/#googtrans%28en%29), not the regular docs. There are slight differences. Enough to always trip you up.
2. Also examples on the Internet are mixed, and often people are NOT clear if they are you using Phonegap CLI or Phonegap Build. Be clear on what the example is meant for. If not, ask the author.
3. For setting up landscape, you only need one setting. It is in the [documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#Preferences) as: 
   `<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />`
4. I also notice your icons and splash screen are not correct. [Here is
   your reference](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens).

In case, you are not getting it you can look at my [Demo for Mobile Popups](https://build.phonegap.com/apps/1510127/share). It is done in landscape mode. The source is on [github](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/mobileui-popup). NOTE: there is a split second where you can see the App rotating into landscape mode. If you are still having a problem, this may be a response bug in your test device. The sense of this problem is best seen in this report: 
[Android Fragmentation Visualized](http://opensignal.com/reports/2014/android-fragmentation/)

Comment: too much test devices have this rotation stuff (in android), so is it solvable?